# Issue with Web browser Control C#

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I am using Webrowser control to go to a url and do a step and that is it.
The issue i am facing is the control works fine for exactly 2 times and then it stops working and does not load the url any more than i realized if i close the application and ran again it again works twice and then same thing . 
I have tried like this approx 5+ times happens each time so this is strange behavior.

The control is inside a thread.

```
 var th = new Thread(() =>
            {
                using (var br = new WebBrowser())
                {
                    br.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;

                    br.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    br.ScrollBarsEnabled = true;
                    br.AllowNavigation = true;

                    br.Navigate(urltoRun);
                    Application.Run();
                }
            });
            th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            th.Start();
            th.Join(60000);
            th = null;
```

And browser_DocumentCompleted:

```
    private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(htmlResult))
            return;
    // DO SOMETHING...
    }
```

Comment: Why are you trying to use a thread to navigate to an URL? The WebBrowser control is event driven, it won't block the UI anyway. It also doesn't work that well in a thread other than the main. No matter if you defined `ApartmentState.STA`. Is there a reason why you decided to *thread* it?

Comment: @Jimi you are right that slipped my mind...but still why that issue above

Comment: The WebBrowser stops working. It's not thread-friendly. There's an answer by Hans Passant and one by Reza Aghaei (that uses Hans Passant's) - that I know of - which show how this *could* be done. You can search it. But I won't suggest to try it in production.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem  and I had an exception, so make sure that "common language runtime exceptions" is checked  in Exception Settings (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> will open the window).

If the webbrowser control isn't that friendly, you can try  using "Cefsharp" for winform.